# Relationship between Symplectic Transvections and Their Associated Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, clifford-group

I'm studying symplectic transvections and their properties in the context of quantum information theory. I came across the definition of a symplectic transvection, $\tau_h$, which maps $\mathbb{F}_{2}^{2m}$ to itself. It is defined as:

$$
\tau_h(x) \equiv x + \langle x, h \rangle h
$$

where $\langle x, h \rangle$ denotes the symplectic product, and $F_h$ is the associated symplectic matrix:

$$
F_h \equiv I_{2m} + \Omega h^Th
$$

where $\Omega$ is the symplectic form.

My understanding is that a transvection is a particular linear transformation, but it does not correspond to a single elementary Clifford operator. I'm trying to understand the deeper connection between the map $\tau_h$ and its associated symplectic matrix $F_h$, beyond their respective definitions.

Could someone please explain or provide insight into the relationship between a symplectic transvection and its associated symplectic matrix? Additionally, how does this relationship illuminate the fact that a transvection does not correspond to a single elementary Clifford operator?

I appreciate any help or references to literature that could further my understanding.

Thank you!!